# http.GET works, but http.post & http.put do not

Tags: asp.net, angular, http

I'm trying to write an Angular 4 app which talks to an ASP.net backend.  'GET' requests work just fine, but I can't get 'POST', 'PUT', or 'DELETE' requests to work.  Here is some sample code:

```
//asp.net server code:
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    public string Post2U([FromUri]string name) { return "name: " + name; }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    public string Post2B([FromBody]string name) { return "name: " + name; }


//Angular code
Post2B(){
  return this.http.post(this.url + "Post2B", {name: 'pops'});
  }

Post2U(){
  return this.http.post(this.url + "Post2U?name=jack");
  }
```

Post2U() doesn't error, but the return string is simply: "name:"  The input parameter isn't reognized.

Post2B() returns a '405 Method not Allowed' error

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing [FromBody] from input parameter.

Comment: The correct is using [FromBody]. The problem is that "the method is not allowed". That's: you must  authorize the method, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JSON.stringify(your_object)` to stringify the body and pass as `{body: body_object}` as second parameter to hhtp.post.

`this.http.post(this.url + "Post2B", {body:JSON.stringify({name: 'pops'})})`

Comment: NOT, If your'e using httpClient NOT use JSON.stringfy